# class cast exception in Android Application

Tags: android

I am getting class cast exception in the below line of code. I have attached the stack trace below and the line below is 339 as mentioned in stack trace.

`com.unique.may.utility.GlobalStateData gs = (com.unique.may.utility.GlobalStateData) 
getApplication();`

In global state data the code is

```
public class GlobalStateData extends Application {

private String findUsBranchEMailId;

public void setFindUsBranchEMailId(String findUsBranchEMailId) {
    this.findUsBranchEMailId = findUsBranchEMailId;
}

public String getFindUsBranchEMailId() {
    return findUsBranchEMailId;
}


}
```

Stack Trace

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application
at com.style.IntlLayout.Find.onChildClick(Find.java:339)
at android.widget.ExpandableListView.handleItemClick(ExpandableListView.java:588)
at android.widget.ExpandableListView.performItemClick(ExpandableListView.java:527)
```

below is my manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.styling.Layout"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP"></uses-permission>
 <support-screens
  android:largeScreens="true"
  android:normalScreens="true"
  android:smallScreens="true"
  android:anyDensity="true"/>

 <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
 <application android:icon="@drawable/launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:debuggable="true">

 <activity android:name=".Catalog" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">    </activity>

     <activity android:name=".Feedback"    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>

     <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"  >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
       </activity>
   </application>


 </manifest>
```

Looking forward to your reply.
thanks.

Comment: AFter you have made some change in the code, clean the project. At times the same exception occurs for me. When I clean the project and run it again, the error vanishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access your `findUsBranchEMailId` like below,

```
((GlobalStateData)getApplication()).setFindUsBranchEMailId("something");
```

And for fetching it,

```
((GlobalStateData)getApplication()).getFindUsBranchEMailId());
```

Also, add your Application class name to the Application Tag in your Manifest file,

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:debuggable="true" android:name=".GlobalStateData">
```

Comment: I have added this line in manifest file
`<activity android:name=".uni.may.utility.GlobalStateData"></activity>`
I tried with your code getting the same exception.

Comment: you just had to add `android:name=".GlobalStateData"`

Comment: thanks, but how can we add two application tags, as I already have one application tag in my manifest file and android does not allow more than one application tag, I tried with just adding the below line but didnt work.
`android:name=".uni.may.utility.GlobalStateData"` do I have to put under ans specific tags. Tried with the below lines but did not work
 `<android:name=".uni.may.utility.GlobalStateData"></android:name>`and also tried with as below
` <android:name=".GlobalStateData"></android:name>`
under application tag.

Comment: ohoo in the same tab just remove `.uni.may.utility.` and put only `.GlobalStateData`

Comment: you mean to say 
`<android:name=".GlobalStateData"></android:name>`
the above didnt work and  below is my application tag
`<application
        android:icon="@drawable/launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:debuggable="true" >'

Comment: thanks but not working 
`<application
        android:icon="@drawable/launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:debuggable="true" 
        android:name=".GlobalStateData">`
thrown exception class not found Exception at the starting of the application.

Comment: You should post your complete Manifest file in the question as well.

Comment: Check this complete example http://www.xoriant.com/blog/mobile-application-development/android-application-class.html

Comment: that's exactly what I have done but still getting the errors.thanks.

Comment: No I guess you are missing something I had done from that only when I was at learning stage :D

Comment: got it working, I opened manifest xml file went to Applications tab and clicked on Browse and navigated to Application class and selected the class and working perfectly. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In order to utilize the getApplication() function, you must first register in your Manifest and the Android automatically instantiates this for you.

```
<application android:name=".ApplicationName"
```

Comment: I have addes this as activity in Manifest file `<activity android:name=".uni.may.utility.GlobalStateData"></activity>`

Comment: Include it in your application tag.

Answer (score 1):

Did you specify this:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#nm?

Comment: I have specified and the code is 
 `<activity android:name=".uni.may.utility.GlobalStateData"></activity>`

Comment: If you look carefully, you'll notice that I am talking about the application node and not an activity node

Comment: thanks I got your point please have a look into the edited manifest file now. Adding even in application node is throwing exceptions. Please have a look into Lalit Poptani comments.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you doing quite wrong,

1. Create your application class something like,

   ```
   class MyApp extends Application {

    private String myState;

    public String getState(){
    return myState;
    }
    public void setState(String s){
    myState = s;
    }
   }
   ```
2. Get your Application class object in activity something like,

   ```
   class Blah extends Activity {

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle b){
   ...
   MyApp appState = ((MyApp)getApplicationContext());
   String state = appState.getState();
   ...
    }
   }
   ```
3. Declare your Application class in manifest file something like,

   ```
   <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".MyApp">
   ```

For more info look at this tutorial [Android Application Class](http://www.xoriant.com/blog/mobile-application-development/android-application-class.html)